# Loop through merged cells in a Column to get their addresses in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have one column. Say column A, which has multiple merged cells of different ranges.

For example first cell is merged from A2 to A15 whereas second merged cell ranges from A16 to A115.

I want to run through entire column to get the address of each merged cell.

The following code only worked for the first cell but I want to loop through all the cells in column A.

```
Sub Macro()

    Dim rng As Range, rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range

    Set rng = Range("A2")

    If rng.MergeCells Then

        Set rng = rng.MergeArea
        Set rngStart = rng.Cells(1, 1)
        Set rngEnd = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)

        MsgBox "First Cell " & rngStart.Address & vbNewLine & "Last Cell " & rngEnd.Address

    Else

        MsgBox "Not merged area"

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's best if you paste in what code you've already written.

Comment: Please include the code you are working with in your question in order to get help with it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it only works for a single cell is because you set `rng` as a single cell. Hence i used a `for each cell in rng` to loop through  column A till the last row.

```
Sub macro()

    Dim rng As Range, rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range, cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim arr() As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row 'Get the last row in the activesheet
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    End With

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Address = cell.Address Then

            If cell.MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then

                arr() = Split(cell.MergeArea.Address, ":")
                Set rngStart = Range(arr(0))
                Set rngEnd = Range(arr(1))
                MsgBox "First Cell " & rngStart.Address & vbNewLine & "Last Cell " & rngEnd.Address

            Else

                MsgBox "Not merged area"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: code runs through entire column A with loop but the problem is it doesn’t goes to the next Merged cell rather it goes to immediate next cell
For eg
My first cell i.e. A1, is single(non-merged) cell. My next cell is merged from A2:A10 followed by merged cell is from A11:A29
So when the code runs it skips the A1 because it is single cell. For upcoming cell, A2- it shows the address correctly
Now ideally it should move to A11 directly but it doesn’t It goes to A3 & shows the same address as of A2 & repeats the same address until it reaches to A10
Can you please fix this issue with the code

Comment: I have edited the answer, try it and let me know if there is any other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sub Macro()

Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim rngEnd As Range

```
Set rng = Range("A2")

If rng.MergeCells Then

    Set rng = rng.MergeArea
    Set rngStart = rng.Cells(1, 1)
    Set rngEnd = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)

    MsgBox "First Cell " & rngStart.Address & vbNewLine & "Last Cell " & rngEnd.Address

Else

    MsgBox "Not merged area"

End If
```

End Sub

this is the code that work for single cell

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should edit your question with this code instead of posting as an answer